# Using Elasticsearch, how do I apply function scores to documents which conditionally have a property

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a handful of indexes, some of which have a particular date property indicating when it was published (`date_publish`), and others do not. I am trying to apply a `gauss` function to decay the score of documents which were published a long time ago. The relevant indexes are correctly configured to recognise the `date_publish` property as a date.

I have set up my query as follows, specifically filtering documents which do not have the property:

```
{
  "index": "index_contains_prop,index_does_not_contains_prop",
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "function_score": {
        "score_mode": "avg",
        "query": {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        "functions": [
          {
            "script_score": {
              "script": {
                "source": "0"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "filter": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "date_publish"
              }
            },
            "gauss": {
              "date_publish": {
                "origin": "now",
                "scale": "728d",
                "offset": "7d",
                "decay": 0.5
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 1000
  }
}
```

However, the query errors with the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "unknown field [date_publish]",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 0
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "index_does_not_contains_prop",
        "node": "1hfXZK4TT3-K288nIr0UWA",
        "reason": {
          "type": "parsing_exception",
          "reason": "unknown field [date_publish]",
          "line": 1,
          "col": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I have RTFM'd many times, and i can't see any discrepancy - I ahve also tried wrapping the `exists` condition in a `bool:must` object, to no avail.

Have I misunderstood the purpose of the `filter` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exists` query will only work on fields that are part of the index mapping. It will return only documents that have a value for this field, but the field itself still needs to be defined in the mapping. This is why you're getting an error - `index_does_not_contains_prop` does not have `date_publish` mapped. You can use the [put mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) API to add this field to the indexes who don't have it (it won't change any document), and then your query should work.

Comment: Thanks Doron, this helped me solve the issue. As far as I understand `exists` is basically an `is null` check, and doesn't apply to `is not there` – misleading operator, but it's solved now!

Comment: Well, not exactly, if you index a document without a certain field (without explicitly setting it to null), it will also return in a "not exists" filter. But it does need to be in the mapping.